# height of html or css

Tags: html, css

I have a website (http://www.errandly.com) and would like to raise the height of the "Copyright" blurb at the footer. I know little about html and css - and have tried searching for answers online and on your site. I am using weebly (an easy drag-and-drop website making site that allows me to change the html and css), and I have pasted the footer's html code below (but not sure what to do with it - or css - in order to raise the height of the footer:

```
    {<div id="footer">%%WEEBLYFOOTER%%</div><div align=center>© Copyright <a href='http://errandly.com/'> Errandly Errand Services Ltd.</a> 2011 All Rights Reserved</div>}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thank you,
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you posted your copyright note below `<div id="footer"> ... </div>`, and your cms created a new element after the footer for it. 
Easiest way to fix would be to copy your copyright notice inside the footer-div. Or you could edit your css, find the block that starts with #footer and set the line "padding: 35px 0 20px;" to "padding:0;"

Comment: I found your answer of changing the css to "padding:0" was easiest for me (a complete layman). I'm confused though as to why the footer has different heights on different pages?  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I played around with it and it is great. Thank you for your help (and thank you to the other responders).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make the element **larger**, you've a few options:

1. Increase the `font-size` of the element: `font-size: 2em;` for example.
2. Apply padding: `padding: 0.5em;` (to apply padding of `0.5em` to `top`, `right`,`bottom` and `left` of the element).
3. specify the `height` directly: `height: 3em;`

I'd also suggest applying an `id` to the element: `<div id="footer">`, and using that as a hook for the css:

```
#footer {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    height: 3em;
}
```

As an alternative interpretation of your question, if you want to simply **move** the element a little higher from the bottom of the page, you can use:

```
#footer {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css style attribute to change the size of your div tag

```
<div style="height:100px" id="footer">%%WEEBLYFOOTER%%</div><div align=center>© Copyright <a href='http://errandly.com/'> Errandly Errand Services Ltd.</a> 2011 All Rights Reserved</div>}
```

Comment: I think when he says, _"raise the height"_, he's speaking as a layman which likely means that he wants to change the position of the footer relative to the bottom of his page.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you want to try add

tags in your HTML file between the  tags of the Footer. Then if you want to change the position of the text within the div of the Footer, just add this code...

```
#footer p {
line-height: 25px;
```

}

Of course 25px is just an option but you'd always want to adding padding at the top and below of the paragraph attribute.

Hope this helps,
Thank you,
Aaron